# Delete blank columns (which have headers) on multiple worksheets within workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I want to remove all blank columns (that have headers) in multiple worksheets within a single workbook.

I have working code, I did not write, that removes all blank columns within an active worksheet.

I want this code to work across multiple worksheets at the same time.

```vb
Sub DeleteBlankColumns()
Dim i As Long
    Dim lnglastcolumn As Long
    Dim delrng As Range
    
    With ActiveSheet
        lnglastcolumn = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        
        For i = 1 To lnglastcolumn
            If .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).row = 1 Then
                If delrng Is Nothing Then
                    Set delrng = .Columns(i)
                Else
                    Set delrng = Union(delrng, .Columns(i))
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    
    delrng.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of `With Activesheet`, use `For Each ws in Worksheets`, followed by `With ws`. Add a `Dim ws as Worksheet` to the other Dim statements, and a `Next` just before the `End Sub`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Sheets object :

```
Sub DeleteBlankColumns(curSheet As Worksheet)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lnglastcolumn As Long
    Dim delrng As Range
    
    With curSheet
        lnglastcolumn = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        
        For i = 1 To lnglastcolumn
            If .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row = 1 Then
                If delrng Is Nothing Then
                    Set delrng = .Columns(i)
                Else
                    Set delrng = Union(delrng, .Columns(i))
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    
    If Not (delrng Is Nothing) Then
        delrng.Delete
    End If
End Sub

Sub Run()
    'DeleteBlankColumns Sheets("Sheet1")
    'DeleteBlankColumns Sheets("Sheet2")
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        DeleteBlankColumns Sheets(sh.Name)
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: Does the last section "Run()" look for sheets with name "Sheet1" etc? If so, that may be an issue as the names of the extra worksheets are client specific and may change each month. Sorry, should have made that clearer in my request

Comment: It is an exemple, In run function, you set all sheet name that you want to process. You can create a loop that goes through all the sheets : what leaves do you want to process? All the sheets in the workbook?

Comment: It will be all worksheets in the workbook please

Comment: add a "for each" loop... I changed my exemple.

Comment: AMAZING! That worked a treat, thank you! Not sure how to mark this as revolved though

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next adapted code:

```
Sub DeleteEmptyColsInAllSheets()
 Dim wb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet, delRng As Range, lnglastcolumn As Long, i As Long
 Set wb = ActiveWorkbook ' use here the workbook you need

 For Each sh In wb.Worksheets
    With sh
        lnglastcolumn = .cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).column
        
        For i = 1 To lnglastcolumn
            If .cells(.rows.count, i).End(xlUp).Row = 1 Then
                If delRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set delRng = .Columns(i)
                Else
                    Set delRng = Union(delRng, .Columns(i))
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    If Not delRng Is Nothing then
        delRng.Delete: Set delRng = Nothing
    End If
 Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. there is an issue with this one: "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set" : (delRng.Delete: Set delRng = Nothing)

Comment: @TigerLily This is part of your code... I only tried making the range `Nothing` for the next sheet. There probably was a sheet not having empty columns and `delRng` is already `Nothing` (`not Set`). So was designed your code. Anyhow, I will adapt mine to preliminarily check this aspect.